# single shot queries don't work in kdb process

Tags: kdb

This `` (hsym`$"host:9999:admin:pass")@({tables[]};`) `` doesn't work.

```
(Roundtrip: 000ms)
ERROR: 'host:9999:admin:pass. OS reports: No such file or directory 
(user-defined signal)
```

This `` hopen`$":host:9999:admin:pass" `` works.

Any ideas why?

We are using KX Control to run our plant if that helps with anything.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show how to replicate this in bare q sessions? Following works for me.

```
KDB+ 4.1t 2022.01.14 Copyright (C) 1993-2022 Kx Systems
m64/ 12()core 65536MB sjt mackenzie.local 127.0.0.1 ...
q)show tbl:([]a:`j`k`l`m;b:til 4)
a b
---
j 0
k 1
l 2
m 3
q)tables[]
,`tbl
q)\p 5999
```

Second session:

```
KDB+ 4.1t 2022.01.14 Copyright (C) 1993-2022 Kx Systems
m64/ 12()core 65536MB sjt mackenzie.local 127.0.0.1 ...

q)(hsym`$"localhost:5999") @ ({tables[]};`)
,`tbl
```

Comment: I don't know how to recreate it. it doesn't work when I trigger it from qpad.